# Rx Exception and different behavior according to SubscribeOn/ObserverOn

Tags: c#, exception, task, system.reactive

I will try to explain my problem and make it simple. I have an Observable that used like this :

```
 Disposable = SaveMarketDataSnapshot(dataSet).Subscribe(OnSave, OnErrorSave, OnCompletedSave);
```

SaveMarketDataSnapshot is defined like this:

```
IObservable<IMarketDataSet> SaveMarketDataSnapshot(List<IMarketDataSet> dataSet)
{
   var obs =  Save(data);

   obs.ObserveOn(SchedulerService.UiScheduler).Subscribe(TrackSavedDataSet);//(case 1)
   return obs;
}
```

In SaveMarketDataSnapshot, I have like a traker that I used for different purposes.

I create Observable with Observable.Create that run a task that do Save operation using REST API call.

```
   public IObservable<MarketDataSet> Save(List<KeyValuePair<string, MarketDataSet>> marketDataSet)
    {
        var obs = Observable.Create<MarketDataSet>(observer =>
        {
            CancellationTokenSource cancellationTokenSource = new CancellationTokenSource();

            Task task = new Task(() => SaveInternal(marketDataSet, observer, cancellationTokenSource.Token), cancellationTokenSource.Token);

            task.Start();

            return Disposable.Create(() => cancellationTokenSource.Cancel());
        });
        return obs;
    }


    void SaveInternal(List<KeyValuePair<string, MarketDataSet>> dataSets, IObserver<MarketDataSet> observer, CancellationToken cancelToken)
    {
        var exceptions = new List<Exception>();

        try
        {
            foreach (var marketDataSet in dataSets)
            {
                try
                {
                    throw new Exception ();//Simulate Issue 
                    observer.OnNext(marketDataSet.Key);
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    exceptions.Add(ex);
                }
                cancelToken.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();
            }

            if (exceptions.Count > 0)
            {
                AggregateException aggExcep = new AggregateException(
                    "Encountered errors while saving marlket data ",
                    exceptions);
                observer.OnError(aggExcep);
            }
            else
            {
                observer.OnCompleted();
            }
        }
    }
```

The SaveMarketDataSet is an external service

```
 void SaveMarketDataSet(MarketDataSet, string)
```

In one of my test I got an exception in the running task (REST API call). Fortunately I catch well the exception and call observer.OnError(ex)

The problem is that when I got the fist exception my application Terminate with unhanded exception. After different test I understand that TrackSavedDataSet is the origin of my crash.

I can resolve the problem by just adding an OnError delegate to my subscription but I want to understand the origin of the problem.
I replace the old subscription like this (case 2) :

```
 obs.Subscribe(TrackSavedDataSet);
```

In this case nothing happen and even the OnErrorSave of my other subscription didn't run.

Finally I replace my call with (case 3)  :

```
obs.SubscribeOn(SchedulerService.NewTaskScheduler).
       Subscribe(TrackSavedDataSet);
```

In this case, OnErrorSave is called and I got UnobservedTaskException.

I think that the origin of this issue is that OnError of the second observer is not handled and an exception is rethrown.

I have this supposition to explain the 3 behavior :

Case 1 : Exception  is thrown in UI thread and stop application ?

Case 2 : Exception is thrown in the same task used to run observable, this break even the first subscription OnError notification ?

Case 3 : Exception is thrown in Task that run the observable (SchedulerService.NewTaskScheduler) and without catch is considered as unobserved ?

Can please someone clarify those behaviors ?

Comment: Do you understand that when Rx gets an `OnError` then that ends the observable subscription? You can only ever get one. I think you need to show all of your code to get a better answer than this.

Comment: Yes I understand but the issue is about having 2 subscribers one handling exception, and one not and the resulting behavior about exception management.

Comment: Could you please show all of your code? We need a [mcve].

Comment: Ok, I added more code

Comment: One of the most important bits of code is the `//EXTERNAL REST API CALL`. Can you show that and the class defs required for it? That's the "complete" part of the [mcve].

Comment: Just as a comment given the existing code - it's a real hodgepodge between Rx and TPL. You should really avoid mixing the two. I suspect that there's a very concise and simple Rx solution. I'm looking forward to seeing the complete code - I should be able to copy, paste and compile the result, effectively.

Comment: I call client.SaveMarketDataSet that encapsulate rest api call to save data.

Comment: Can you show **all the code** please? i.e. what is `client.SaveMarketDataSet(marketDataSet);`? What are their types? etc. Please show the types as well.

Comment: Done, SaveMarketDataSet is just external service I call

Comment: What are their types? etc. Please show the types as well. `client` etc. Everything. Please let me **copy, paste, and compile** your code.

Comment: You understand that the lack of answers is because we can't easily work with your code? I need to know how to set up your code and run it. Then I can see the error you're getting and fix it. You need a [mcve].

Comment: Do you understand what I'm asking for?

Comment: Thanks Enigmativity, the exception is thrown by SaveMarketDataSet.Then   to reproduce the issue, call to SaveMarketDataSet can be replaced with Throw new Exception(); and Observable.Defer(...) can be just replaced by calling Save. Do you need more details ?

Comment: Sorry, but I'm giving up. I need to be able to **copy, paste and compile** your code. You shouldn't make me have to figure out what your code does. You should provide us with code that we can run. Then we can help.